# Update Cron Expressions minute and hour through split mechanism

Tags: javascript, split

I have the below cron expression generated.

```
"0 8 9 9 1/8 ? *"
```

After spliting by space, the first index fetches minutes and the second index fetches the hour. 
Can i replace the minute and hour value and keep the same cron expression with other properties?

Eg: Currently the time is set to 9:08, I need to update to 10:30

Thanks in Advance

Comment: yes of course you can. amend the array. join it

Comment: Done, Thanks !!!